# Docker - Namespaces query

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, kernel

Whenever I spin up a new docker container, what actually happens under the hood in terms of namespaces? What I understand is that - when I create a container named "X", X will get its own instance of each kernel namespace of IPC, Network, Mount, PID, User, UTS and container "Y" will get its own instance of namespace IPC, Network, Mount, PID, User, UTS etc. Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can also control it yourself and decide to share namespaces
See `--pid, --uts, --net` for more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)
i.e, You can decide to have the same pid namespace as host by using `--pid=host`, and then when executing `top` or `ps aux`, you'll see the same details as running the command on your host

Under the hood, its exactly the same as cloning a new process with `CLONE_NEWPID`, See [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) for details for each namespace